# Force numpy to keep a list a list

Tags: python, numpy

`x2_Kaxs` is an Nx3 numpy array of lists, and the elements in those lists index into another array. I want to end up with an Nx3 numpy array of lists of those indexed elements.

```
x2_Kcids = array([ ax2_cid[axs] for axs in x2_Kaxs.flat ], dtype=object)
```

This outputs a (N*3)x1 array of numpy arrays. great. that almost works for what I want. All I need to do is reshape it.

```
x2_Kcids.shape = x2_Kaxs.shape
```

And this works.`x2_Kcids` becomes an Nx3 array of numpy arrays. Perfect.

Except all the lists in `x2_Kaxs` only have one element in them. Then it flattens 
it into an Nx3 array of integers, and my code expects a list later in the pipeline.

One solution I came up with was to append a dummy element and then pop it off, but that is very ugly. Is there anything nicer?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not really about lists of size 1, it is about list all of the same size. I have created this dummy samples:

```
ax2_cid = np.random.rand(10)
shape = (10, 3)

x2_Kaxs = np.empty((10, 3), dtype=object).reshape(-1)
for j in xrange(x2_Kaxs.size):
    x2_Kaxs[j] = [random.randint(0, 9) for k in xrange(random.randint(1, 5))]
x2_Kaxs.shape = shape

x2_Kaxs_1 = np.empty((10, 3), dtype=object).reshape(-1)
for j in xrange(x2_Kaxs.size):
    x2_Kaxs_1[j] = [random.randint(0, 9)]
x2_Kaxs_1.shape = shape

x2_Kaxs_2 = np.empty((10, 3), dtype=object).reshape(-1)
for j in xrange(x2_Kaxs_2.size):
    x2_Kaxs_2[j] = [random.randint(0, 9) for k in xrange(2)]
x2_Kaxs_2.shape = shape
```

If we run your code on these three, the return has the following shapes:

```
>>> np.array([ax2_cid[axs] for axs in x2_Kaxs.flat], dtype=object).shape
(30,)
>>> np.array([ax2_cid[axs] for axs in x2_Kaxs_1.flat], dtype=object).shape
(30, 1)
>>> np.array([ax2_cid[axs] for axs in x2_Kaxs_2.flat], dtype=object).shape
(30, 2)
```

And the case with all lists of length 2 won't even let you reshape to `(n, 3)`. The problem is that, even with `dtype=object`, numpy tries to *numpify* your input as much as possible, which is all the way down to individual elements if all lists are of the same length. I think that your best bet is to preallocate your `x2_Kcids` array:

```
x2_Kcids = np.empty_like(x2_Kaxs).reshape(-1)
shape = x2_Kaxs.shape
x2_Kcids[:] = [ax2_cid[axs] for axs in x2_Kaxs.flat]
x2_Kcids.shape = shape
```

---

**EDIT** Since unubtu's answer is no longer visible, I am going to steal from him. The code above can be much more nicely and compactly written as:

```
x2_Kcids = np.empty_like(x2_Kaxs)
x2_Kcids.ravel()[:] = [ax2_cid[axs] for axs in x2_Kaxs.flat]
```

---

With the above example of single item lists:

```
>>> x2_Kcids_1 = np.empty_like(x2_Kaxs_1).reshape(-1)
>>> x2_Kcids_1[:] = [ax2_cid[axs] for axs in x2_Kaxs_1.flat]
>>> x2_Kcids_1.shape = shape
>>> x2_Kcids_1
array([[[ 0.37685372], [ 0.95328117], [ 0.63840868]],
       [[ 0.43009678], [ 0.02069558], [ 0.32455781]],
       [[ 0.32455781], [ 0.37685372], [ 0.09777559]],
       [[ 0.09777559], [ 0.37685372], [ 0.32455781]],
       [[ 0.02069558], [ 0.02069558], [ 0.43009678]],
       [[ 0.32455781], [ 0.63840868], [ 0.37685372]],
       [[ 0.63840868], [ 0.43009678], [ 0.25532799]],
       [[ 0.02069558], [ 0.32455781], [ 0.09777559]],
       [[ 0.43009678], [ 0.37685372], [ 0.63840868]],
       [[ 0.02069558], [ 0.17876822], [ 0.17876822]]], dtype=object)
>>> x2_Kcids_1[0, 0]
array([ 0.37685372])
```

Comment: @unubtu Since you deleted your answer, I have shamelessly copied your flattened-array-on-the-left-of-assignment in an edit to my answer. Had to go with `.ravel()` though, as `.flat` was giving weird results.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Denis:

```
if x.ndim == 2:
    x.shape += (1,)
```